# countdown timer service in global process android

Tags: android, service, process, global

1. I am trying to make a timer which will run even when the app is killed. I have found a solution to use a service. But the service restarts every time i kill the app. 
According to my research the workaround is to put the service in global process, i have tried that but does not work for me. 
I am using android studio 2.0 and API 23 as a target.

2. Even if i manage to get the timer working in background, it will still stop if the device is turned off or in case of dead battery, so would it be a good idea to run the timer on server?
   Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Running timer in service makes battery low very fastly. I dont know your requirement but you can use datestamp according to device time.

Comment: I am trying to make a countdown timer which displays the timer to the user as well as keeps running even if app is closed. At the end of the countdown it can trigger some notification.
Now there are 2 options.
1. if i use AlarmManager, the trigger happens but i can't find a way to show the countdown to the user.
2. if i use CountdownTimer, user can see the time counting down but the service restarts as the app is killed.
any help around this would be appreciated.